# How to insert a plot over foreach() loop?

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, doparallel, openxlsx

Is is possible to add plot inside a `foreach()% dopar{}` loop?

I'm using the below code, but it does not insert the image using `foreach`. It works perfectly with the for-loop though.

How it works over a foreach loop?

```
{rm(list = ls())
  library(dplyr)
  library(imager)
  library(openxlsx)
  }

library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
cl <- makeCluster(4)
registerDoParallel(cl)

#for(i in 1:3){ 
foreach(i = 1:3, .combine = cbind, .packages = c("dplyr","imager","openxlsx"))%dopar% {
     file<-paste0(i,".xlsx")
     wb<-createWorkbook(file)
     addWorksheet(wb, "test", gridLines = T)
     Logo<- imager::load.image("~/YY.PNG")
     print(Logo)
     insertPlot(wb, sheet = "test", width = 2, height =1, fileType = "png", units = "in")
     saveWorkbook(wb, file, overwrite = TRUE)
  }
stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are not just using `insertImage()` to directly insert the image? `insertPlot` seems to reply on `dev.copy()` which probably isn't working for the "headless" default device. You probably will have to write the plot to a file, and then use `insertImage()` to get it to work.

Comment: I didn't know that. I will try it and update. Thanks for your hint.

Comment: I face with error in applying the below instead of insertPlot, as Invalid file... Can you please advise.  ```insertImage(wb, sheet = "Summary", file= Logo, width = 2, height =1, units = "in",startRow = 1, startCol = 1)```

Comment: What’s the error?

Comment: ```Error in file.exists(file) : invalid 'file' argument```

Comment: Are you still using imager? Rather than `file=Logo`, pass the path `file=“~/YY.PNG”`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @MrFlick, the answer is as below:

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
cl <- makeCluster(4)
registerDoParallel(cl)

foreach(i = 1:3, .combine = cbind, .packages = c("dplyr","imager","openxlsx"))%dopar% {
  file<-paste0(i,".xlsx")
  wb<-createWorkbook(file)
  addWorksheet(wb, "test", gridLines = T)
  img <- "~/YY.png"
  insertImage(wb, sheet = "test", img, width = 2, height =1, units = "in",startRow = 1, startCol = 1)
  saveWorkbook(wb, file, overwrite = TRUE)
}
stopCluster(cl)
```